# WordPress Multiple Loops Confusion

Tags: wordpress

I have multiple loops that I want to display on my WordPress blog. The categories are as follows:

- Top-story (1 per page)
- Small-story (1 per page)
- Normal (1 per page)
- Quickfill (2 per page)

I've got 4 loops to display these. I'm trying to display this amount of posts per page and once they've been displayed, don't show them again on another page, as I don't want to show duplicates.

My loops are as follows. I seem to be getting duplicates and when I'm trying to get them to remove duplicates I tend to remove everything without knowing how.

**Top story - 1st loop**

```
<?php 
        global $do_not_duplicate;
        $do_not_duplicate = array();

        $paged = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
        $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=top-story&posts_per_page=1&paged='.$paged);

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
        // content
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Small-story - 2nd loop**

```
<?php 
        $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=small-story&posts_per_page=1&paged='.$paged);
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;
        $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; 
        ?>
        // content
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Normal posts (note: the category is actually called normal) - 3rd loop**

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=normal&posts_per_page=1&paged='.$paged);
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;
        $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; ?>
        // content
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Quickfill - 4th loop**

```
<?php   
        $int = 0;
        $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=quickfill&posts_per_page=2&paged='.$paged);

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        if (in_array($post->ID, $do_not_duplicate)) continue;       
        $do_not_duplicate[] = $post->ID; 
            if ($int==0) { ?>
                <hr class="seperator" />
                <div class="gr_bg_post">
                    <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/quickfill.png" />
            <?php } ?>
                <div class="fl">
                    <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                    <?php the_content('<button type="button" class="read_more_green">Read More</button>'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php if ($int==1) { ?>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php $int++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

**Last loop - standard WordPress protocol for display posts... (I think this may have something to do with my duplicates)**

```
<?php
        $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_not_in' => $do_not_duplicate));
        if (have_posts()) : while ($my_query>have_posts()) : $my_query>the_post();
        ?>
        // content
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now and I just can't seem to stop duplicates showing, or get the correct posts to show. Any help is **greatly** appreciated!

Comment: Try resetting your queries, that maybe the problem - <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query

Comment: Still having the same problem after reseting my queries.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the query variable `$my_query` in the last query

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_not_in' => $do_not_duplicate));

if ($my_query->have_posts()) : while ($my_query>have_posts()) : $my_query>the_post();
    // content
endwhile; endif;
```